# Closing Pygame games made with PyScripter in Portable Python closes PyScripter too

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.6, portable-applications, pyscripter

I am using Portable Python to to some PyGame development because it has PyGame and PyScripter built in so there was minimal setup.
I write the code, then press run and my game launches. When I close the game (by the Windows "X", not some in-game close button), PyScripter closes too.

Are they both part of the same process because they're portable?

Is there a way I can write games to not close pyscripter too?

Or should I set up regular pyscripter and add pygame to it manually?

Cheers

Comment: Possible. Why bother with portable X anyway if you don't need the "portable" part? Installing it "regularily" gives you more recent Python (2.7 or 3.1 as opposed to 2.5/2.6 or 3.0) and Pygame versions and avoids such hassle, with the only downside being (1) minimally more "effort" to install and (2) being able to run it from e.g. USB flash drive (which you obviously don't need since you consider using the non-portable version).

Comment: This has nothing to do with "portable" part. This is normal PyScripter setting to run in Internal mode. Even if you install Python, PyScripter in this mode will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your game with PyScripter "Internal" engine. Thats why it closes PyScripter when you close your app. This is normal behavior of PyScripter but there is much more "run modes" you can use.

You can switch to use one of the Remote engines and then your app will run in "external" process. More info:

http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/RemoteEngines